Using CSS how can I show an element only when the parent is overflowing?
Using CSS, how can I show an element only when the parent content is overflowing?
(This is known as a "show more" button.)
Answer requirements:

The content has a fixed max-height
The child content can contain any content (text, images, etc)
The solution has to be CSS only.

CSS only is a very strict requirement. CSS only is faster, has no flicker on startup, is more responsive, etc.
Non-working Code


.container {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.big-content {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  height: 200px;
}

.small-content {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, white);
  height: 50px;
}

.overflow-message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="big-content"></div>
    <div class="overflow-message">Overflowing (visible)</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="small-content"></div>
    <div class="overflow-message">Not overflowing (not visible)</div>
</div>



Research
No similar question is CCS-only.

How to toggle show more button if text overflow
How to create a "show more" button and specify how many lines of text can be initially shown
ReactJS How to implement Show More Button?
Flutter Markdown "Show more" button
Show more button in html
Flutter Markdown "Show more" button


CSS is fast because it works by applying a one-way transformation to the DOM, taking into consideration external factors like the browser window size, to give you the end page-layout - which means CSS (intentionally) lacks any kind of internal feedback loop where styles depend on the computed results of another style. In lieu of that, I suppose the best you can do would be a @media query that tries to match the exact browser size/conditions where the unwanted layout happens and special-cases it.

@Dai, maybe, but I can make another element positioned depending on the position of another element. Doesn't this make the the style depend on the computed result of another style? Using transform I can even make a style depend on itself. It just seems like there must be a way to do this.

No, it's not. What I meant was that you cannot apply a different CSS style-rule based on the computed style of another element. e.g. using positioned-elements (or the cool new  anchor positioning feature) doesn't mean you can have background-color: blue when the element is on the right side of the page or make it border: 10px dashed red when it's on the left side of the page.

@yeerk Belatedly: The existence of other questions which break the norms of the site is not an excuse to continue doing it yourself.  If you see something amiss, fix it.  Don't use it as justification.  For more information on the debate, as it were, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often

Yes, we can use CSS max-height and calc which have been supported in Chrome since 2013.
Hide If Overflowing
The idea is that we can push the "show more" button down if there is remaining space, but leave it unchanged if there is no remaining space.

calc(MAX-HEIGHT - 100%)

Calculate the remaing space using calc and -


calc((MAX-HEIGHT - 100%) * 10000)

Multiply by a large number, so 1px remaining results in an a large offset. This prevents the button from being partially visible.


position: absolute; bottom: calc((MAX-HEIGHT - 100%) * 10000);

Offset the button from the bottom.
If there is any remaining space, bottom will be set to a large negative value, resulting in the button being hidden.



Overflowing Example
Putting it together, gives us bottom: calc((100% - 100px) * 10000);, for a container  which has a max-height: 100px.
The linear gradient is overflowing, which can be seen as it cuts off before it finishes the gradient.


.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  
  & .content {
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px; /* greater-than container height */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  }
  
  & .message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc((100% - 100px) * 10000);
    background: white;
  }
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="message">
        Overflowing
    </div>
</div>



Non-overflowing Example
The linear gradient does not cut off, so the text is not visible.


.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  
  & .content {
    width: 10px;
    height: 99px; /* less-than container height */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  }
  
  & .message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc((100% - 100px) * 10000);
    background: white;
  }
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="message">
        Not overflowing so this text is not visible
    </div>
</div>




Hmm… and I guess this could work in a container with a fixed height (versus a max-height) by putting this inside, with the max-height of the inner container matching the height of the other container? That’s clever, I love this kind of hack.

Adding a solution for the future using scroll-driven animations where you don't need to know the value of max-height or height.
You can test it using the latest version of chrome


.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;

  .message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation: show;
    animation-timeline: scroll();
  }
}
@keyframes show {
  0%,100% {visibility: visible}   
}

/* irrelevant CSS */
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content" style="height: 90px;"></div>
    <div class="message">
        You don't see me because we don't reach max-height
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content" style="height: 110px"></div>
    <div class="message">
        You see me because we reach max-height
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="max-height: 200px;">
    <div class="content" style="height: 110px"></div>
    <div class="message">
        You don't see me because we increased the max-height
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="height: 80px;max-height: auto;">
    <div class="content" style="height: 110px"></div>
    <div class="message">
        It works with height as well
    </div>
</div>



More detail available on my blog: https://css-tip.com/overflow-detection/

That is clean! I wonder if this behavior (not applying any key frames until there’s possible scrolling) is guaranteed by the spec or if it might not work in anll implementations.

@JeremyBanks yes it's defined to work like that by the Spec

Nice. Some relevant quotes, I was curious: "If the source of a ScrollTimeline is an element whose principal box does not exist or is not a scroll container, or if there is no scrollable overflow, then the ScrollTimeline is inactive." "A user agent adds scroll bars to an element box to make it a scroll container when the CSS overflow property is set to scroll or when overflow is set to auto and the content overflows the container." "A time value can be unresolved, i.e. represent the absence of a meaningful time value. This can happen if a timing node is not in a state to produce a time value."
